# Speed up Optimisation by saving results of previous function calls

Tags: r, performance, mathematical-optimization

When you do an optimization in R, often the function is evaluated with the same parameters several times. If the function takes a long time this represents an inefficiency.

I came up with a solution to improve this by creating a data.frame to store previous function runs but wanted to ask if anyone has a better solution or if it is possible to feed the results of previous function runs directly to any optimization function.

### Example

We want to maximize IntensiveFunction which takes alot of time to calculate (of course not in example case)

```
library(data.table)
library(bbmle)
library(optimx)

IntensiveFunction = function(a,b,d,e){
  (a-1)^2 + (b-2)^2 + (d-3)^2 +(e-4)^2
}
```

Creating Table to store results of previous function runs

```
ResultStore = data.table(A = c(0),B = c(0),D = c(0),E = c(0),Result = c(IntensiveFunction(0,0,0,0)), key = "A,B,D,E")
```

Function to retrieve or calculate & store function runs

```
ToOptimise = function(a,b,d,e){
  if(is.na(ResultStore[J(a,b,d,e), "Result", with = FALSE][[1]]) == FALSE){
      cat("Got Value from Result Store", "\n")
      return(ResultStore[J(a,b,d,e), "Result", with = FALSE][[1]])
  } else {
      cat("Calculating", "\n")
      result = IntensiveFunction(a,b,d,e)
      ResultStore <<- data.table(rbind(ResultStore, data.frame("A" = a,"B" = b,"D" = d,"E" = e,"Result" = result), use.names=TRUE ), key = "A,B,D,E")
      return(result)
  }
}

ToOptimiseForOptimX = function(Theta){
  ToOptimise(Theta[1],Theta[2],Theta[3],Theta[4])
}
```

Optimisations

```
Calibration1 = mle2(ToOptimise, 
                   start = list(a = 1, d = 10),
                   fixed = list(b = 6, e = 10))

Calibration2 = mle2(ToOptimise, 
                   start = list(a = 1, b = 6, d = 10, e = 14))


Calibration3 = optimx(par = c(1,1,1,1),
                      fn = ToOptimiseForOptimX,
                      control = list(all.methods = TRUE))
```

One thing you can notice when you run this is that even the first time you run Calibration1 it takes 5 evaluations from ResultStore meaning that it is over-evaluating the function (not remembering previous runs).

### Questions

1. Has anyone encountered this problem and come up with a faster/ cleaner/ better solution to the above?
2. Is there any way to feed a data.frame of function evaluations directly to an optimisation package? It is conceivable that having access to a frame of function evaluations may mean the optimizer may not have to do some evaluations.

Comment: Have you looked at the [memoise](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memoise/index.html) package? If your parameters are real valued (non-integer), then is seems unlikely that R will call with the exact same parameters that many times. Pre-building a grid seems like a waste of time because if there is no exact match, the grid wont be used. After those first 5, do you see a lot of repeats? I think those are a side effect of loop unrolling perhaps.

Comment: I second the various memoization options.  Another option would be closures, but I haven't looked closely enough to determine if that would work here.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the memorise package - that will make the code alot nicer. I agree that a grid is not a good idea but saving previous function calls would be handy to speed up some optimisations, especially something like Optimx where several procedures may be done on the same function.

Comment: After the first five there are alot of repeats. For instance if you run the above code in sequence you see alot more in Calibration2 and Calibration3 as a database is built up.